# i got " TypeError: this._renderer.setElementStyle is not a function" when i open Super tabs page in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2-select

Please find the exact error in screenshot

i am getting this error while running the ionic app can anyone can tell what is this error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ2fj.png

Comment: fanTabs is my root page of superTabs.

Comment: Please put the error in your question and not in an image.

Answer (score 0):

This currently is a [known issue](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs/issues/83) in SuperTabs, it was fixed for Ionic 3.4 but appears to be a regression when using Ionic 3.6.